# Как сделать вывод данных из бинарного файла Си?

Tags: c, структуры-данных

Стоит задача разработать структуру данных для представления простейшей базы данных. Также нужно составить программу генерации внешнего нетекстового файла заданной структуры. С этим я справилась:

Структура:

```
#ifndef _grad_h_

#define _grad_h_

#define NAME_SIZE 50

typedef struct{
    char lname[NAME_SIZE];
    char initials[2];
    char gender[1];
    int school_num;
    char has_medal[NAME_SIZE];
    int rating;
    char essay[NAME_SIZE];
}person;

#endif
```

Скрипт-генератор выходного файла:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "structure.h"

int readperson(FILE *in, person *stud){
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->lname);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->initials);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->gender);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &stud->school_num);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->has_medal);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &stud->rating);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->essay);

    return !feof(in);
}
int writeperson_bin(FILE *out, person *stud){
    fwrite(stud->lname, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
    fwrite(stud->initials, sizeof(char), 2, out);
    fwrite(stud->gender, sizeof(char), 2, out);
    fwrite(&stud->school_num, sizeof(int), 1, out);
    fwrite(stud->has_medal, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
    fwrite(&stud->rating, sizeof(int), 1, out);
    fwrite(stud->essay, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(!in || !out){
        printf("Error, can't open file\n");
    }
    person stud;
    while(readperson(in, &stud)){
        writeperson_bin(out, &stud);
    };

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Последняя программа структурирует данные и сохраняет в бинарник. Однако нужно вывести данные из этого бинарника, в чем и заключается проблема. Пишу программу для вывода, удачно компилирую, выводит кривой набор символов или пустых строк

В чем может быть ошибка?

Программа для вывода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "structure.h"

int readperson(FILE *in, person *stud){
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->lname);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->initials);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->gender);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &stud->school_num);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->has_medal);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &stud->rating);
    fscanf(in, "%s", stud->essay);

    return !feof(in);
}
int writeperson_bin(FILE *out, person *stud){
    fwrite(stud->lname, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
    fwrite(stud->initials, sizeof(char), 2, out);
    fwrite(stud->gender, sizeof(char), 2, out);
    fwrite(&stud->school_num, sizeof(int), 1, out);
    fwrite(stud->has_medal, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
    fwrite(&stud->rating, sizeof(int), 1, out);
    fwrite(stud->essay, sizeof(char), NAME_SIZE, out);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if(!in || !out){
        printf("Error, can't open file\n");
    }
    person stud;
    while(readperson(in, &stud)){
        writeperson_bin(out, &stud);
    };

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у тебя в структуре :

```
char initials[2]; //   два байта
char gender[1]; // один байт
```

а записываешь ты сколько байтов :

```
fwrite(stud->initials, sizeof(char), 2, out);  // два байта
fwrite(stud->gender, sizeof(char), 2, out);   // два байта
```

gender   это  чего   ??  пол я так понимаю,  можна массивом не делать,   просто char gender

количество   байтов которое в файл записываешь обязательно должно соответствовать    количеству которое считываешь

Comment: И тут возникает старое доброе понятие *record* или *записи*...

Comment: @0andriy    ну я не знаю  чего там возникает,    обьяснил  как сам  понимаю

Comment: https://www.pascal-programming.info/lesson11.php Не зря Паскаль вначале хорошо на это дело ложился... https://wiki.freepascal.org/Databases

Comment: @0andriy   а,   во  как ,   понял